# How to generate these vectors quickly in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I want to generate all the vectors of length `n` such that exactly `k` components of the `n` positions are +1 or -1 (there are no restrictions on it being +1 or -1), and the remaining n-k components are all zero.

I can write the code as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations, product
result = []    
for x in combinations(range(n),k):
    for y in product([-1,1],repeat=k)
        zero = [0] * n
        for a in x:
            for b in y:
                zero[a] = b
                result.append(zero)
```

This way works, but I think it is a bit tedious. Is there any fast way to give the result?

Comment: Are you *sure* that does what you want it to?  Your inner loops seem odd, and you seem to produce output which doesn't match your description.

Comment: Why don't you add an example of what you want your vectors to look like. Are there no restrictions on +1 vs -1 (then all +1 would be fine), or do you want a random distribution?

Comment: You can use `numpy` to quickly generate vectors that have k out of n random positions filled with +1 or -1 and the rest with zeros.

Comment: What's wrong with using `itertools.permutations()` directly? `itertools.permute([1]*k + [0]*(n-k))` should more than suffice. You can exclude duplicates with `set()`.

Comment: Add a one liner: set([pl for p in map(permutations, [[0]*(n-k) + l for l in [[1]*i + [-1]*(k-i) for i in range(k+1)]]) for pl in p])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write the function that generates all vectors of length `n` with `k` 1s and `n - k` 0s:

```
def gen(n, k):
    for indices in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        l = [0] * n
        for i in indices:
            l[i] = 1
        yield(l)
```

Then, let's turn some of the 1s into -1s:

```
def gen(n, k):
    for indices in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        # each one of indices can be -1 or +1
        for i in range(len(indices) + 1):
            for neg_indices in itertools.combinations(indices, i):
                l = [0] * n
                for i in indices:
                    l[i] = 1
                for i in neg_indices:
                    l[i] = -1
                yield(l)
```

Sample output:

```
>>> list(gen(3, 2))
[[1, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [1, -1, 0], [-1, -1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1], [1, 0, -1], [-1, 0, -1], [0, 1, 1], [0, -1, 1], [0, 1, -1], [0, -1, -1]]
```

Your original implementation is fairly close; to fix it:

```
def gen(n, k):
    for x in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        for y in itertools.product([-1,1], repeat=k):
            zero = [0] * n
            for a, b in zip(x, y):
                zero[a] = b
            yield zero
```

Note the use of `zip` instead of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
import random
import itertools

# create a single sample vector containing the distribution of elements
base_list = map(lambda x: random.choice([1,-1]), range(k)) + [0]*(n-k)

# generate all unique permutations of this list
result = set(itertools.permutations(base_list))
```

`result` will now contain all unique permutations by value of a base vector contained in `base_list`.

The resulting permutations are all guaranteed to have `k` elements that are either -1 or 1 and `n-k` elements that are all zero.

`set()` takes care of making sure duplicate entries - since `permutations()` permutes by index, not value - are excluded.

This implementation is doubtless going to be slow for large `n`, but for smallish lists should be sufficient.